# Keep model updated from python list in pyQt

Tags: python, qt

This is the first time using Qt or pyQt, and I'm trying to make a simple list with columns. From the pyQt examples, in the basicsortfiltermode.py, which shows how to create a list with columns and which is sortable, the data collection it self is created by using a QStandardItemModel, which has insertRow and setData, but the data is made of String and QDateTime in this example.

From reading the [Model-View guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) as recommended by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996193/looking-for-a-pyqt5-tutorial), I quote:

> All item models are based on the QAbstractItemModel class. This class defines an interface that is used by views and delegates to access data. **The data itself does not have to be stored in the model; it can be held in a data structure or repository provided by a separate class, a file, a database, or some other application component.**

How would I proceed to use a python list to store data and make the view read from the list and any update on the list would be propagated in the view?

Comment: If you want to stick with `QStandardItemModel`, all you need to do is `clear()` it and repopulate it with new data when list is changed.

Comment: How can you associate an object of interest to a ModelIndex? If I select a line, I would like to do stuff with object outside Qt!

Comment: You can use `QModelIndex::row` to get the row of the item, or use `QStandardItem::setData` and `QStandardItem::data` to attach arbitrary data to item (you can also access it with `QModelIndex::data`).